# A column of database type "geometry" results in two extra columns hidden from ssms

Tags: t-sql, spatial

If I create a table like

```
create table test2 (foo geometry)
```

foo will show up in the table designer as expected

[image: screenshot in ssms]

but when I query `sys.columns` for column information...

```sql
select
t.name as TABLE_NAME,
c.name as COLUMN_NAME,
c.precision as PRECISION,
c.scale as SCALE,
c.max_length as MAX_LENGTH,
c.is_nullable as IS_NULLABLE,
ty.name as DATA_TYPE
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN sys.types ty on c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id and ty.NAME != 'sysname'
ORDER BY c.column_id
```

...I also got a columns of the types `hiearchyid` and `geography` (using the same column name).

[image]

Why?

Can I change my `sys.columns` query to filter out those pseudo columns?

(I am using that query to recreate a `create table` query).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this query instead:

```
select
t.name as TABLE_NAME,
c.name as COLUMN_NAME,
c.precision as PRECISION,
c.scale as SCALE,
c.max_length as MAX_LENGTH,
c.is_nullable as IS_NULLABLE,
ty.name as DATA_TYPE
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN sys.types ty on c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id and ty.NAME != 'sysname'
ORDER BY c.column_id
```

the join is based on the **user_type_id** so the results are the same as the GUI.